# What is happening with my Gollum Jade?

Tags: diagnosis, succulents, container-gardening, jade

This plant stays outdoors and gets afternoon sun couple hours. I water it once a week.

What is happening to the ends?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Mayra!  Welcome to our site.  Need a few questions answered so that we can get you an answer.  First;  what is your zone or where do you live?  How cold does it get there?  Even if it is just nights and seldom?  Second, what and how much fertilizer have you used if any?  Third, have you ever allowed your Jade (totally Shrek!) to go too long without some water?  Once a week might be too much but has it ever looked wrinkled a little bit?  Gone on a long vacation?  I think there are a couple of things going on with this plant, not just one. Nothing too awful tho.

Comment: I live in central California, kern county. In the summer it gets up to the triple digits and in the winter sometimes below freezing. Right now it goes up to the high 70s and in the morning and nights in the 50s. I haven't used any fertilizer .. yea I water it when it's dry, usually once a week.

Answer (score 2):

Jade plant is susceptible to sunburn. If you take it out doors and plop it in full sun, you'll get something that looks like you have. The plants usually recover by putting out new leaves with chloroplasts/thylakoids arranged so as not to capture too much energy. Sun angle is changing rapidly this time of year, before spring solstice, so you may be getting a lot more sun in the usual spot than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

My jade, not gollum, has this as well, I think.  If your jade were babied and lived in a green house it probably would be more...pristine.  Having to deal with the weather, seriously hot to below freezing would account for this guy's 'scars'. The tips would be damaged first by the cold or heat. Not a disease, not insects, more in the category of mechanical damage from being out of doors and surviving extreme temperatures.  I would most definitely give it a little fertilizer.  Go get a small bottle of OSMOCOTE granules/beads; 14-14-14.  Use only once per year according to their directions but don't give every 3 months! Your watering sounds just fine especially since this plant is out doors.  I'd use bottled water, distilled water not the tap water.  And looking a bit closer, I think he will love some fertilizer.  Looks great for getting along with nothing but the soil you gave him.  But tis time.  See the spots and uneven color...a bit too light of a green and transparent.  The plant behind him is in need as well, those purplish reddish margins show lack of phosphorus or magnesium.  Don't use epsom salts, trust me.  It does add magnesium sulfate but doesn't really do much for plants. That is the most recent FAD these days.